Configuring JAX WS Client to maintain all received cookies
I'm looking for a way to configure a JAX WS BindingProvider to maintain all cookies received in the set-cookie header response. I know about the javax.xml.ws.session.maintain property but this configuration only maintains the JSESSIONID cookie. I want to maintain all cookies.
This is needed for cookies that are set by a load balancer for sticky sessions for example or other "intermediary" cookies that might be set by a proxy between my client and my server.
I am not looking for a manual way where I retrieve all the cookies on each response and put them back before each request! This is not maintainable. I want a global setup where all set-cookie results will be maintained across the whole duration of the BindingProvider lifecycle.
I am not looking for implementation specific features (e.g. Metro only features)!

How do you mean it is "not maintainable" to manage the cookies using jax-ws API? Everything needed is there and quite straight forward to use, so it's not unlike any other stuff that needs to be developed and maintained.

I have 200 different remote calls. I don't want to go to each one of them and wrap them in a "pre-post cookie handling" method or something similar. I'd expect for the library to provide such functionality.

You don't have to. You can use a ClientResponseFilter to catch all cookies and a ClienRequestFilter to add the appropriate ones for each request. All centralized without having to touch existing code.
